# How can i make a call to a helper from sails console?

Tags: sails.js, helper

im trying to make a helloworld helper in sails.js (the example [here](https://sailsjs.com/documentation/concepts/helpers))

my file is get.js and sails name the helper function like get()

get.js file:

```js
module.exports = {

  friendlyName: 'Format welcome message',

  description: 'Return a personalized greeting based on the provided name.',

  inputs: {

    name: {
      type: 'string',
      example: 'Ami',
      description: 'The name of the person to greet.',
      required: true
    }

  },

  fn: async function (inputs, exits) {
    var result = `Hello, ${inputs.name}!`;
    return exits.success(result);
  }

};
```

but when i make this in the sails console

```js
await sails.helpers.get("john")
```

it returns an error:

```
SyntaxError: await is only valid in async function
```

i cant find where is the error, or if there is an error. what could be wrong?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The error you're seeing is because you can only `await` a function's return from within another `async` function. If you're calling the code "straight from the console" it'll blow up as you've seen.

For quick testing/tinkering you can get the return value from your helper in the console using `.then()`

```js
sails.helpers.get("john").then(console.log).catch(console.error)
```

```js
sails.helpers.get("john").then((greeting) => {
  console.log('Got greeting:', greeting)
}).catch(console.error);
```

Or, by wrapping the helper call in an async [IIFE](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Immediately_invoked_function_expression) then using `await`.

```js
(async () => {
  let greeting = await sails.helpers.get("john")
  console.log(greeting)
})();
```

Comment: Or u can use `sails.helpers.get("john").log()`. The log behaves as if you put await in front of the helper. If I remember, Mike Mcneil said that in the future sails console will support await.